# Android/Java: Incorporating a specific Unicode character in app

Tags: java, android, unicode

I'm putting together an android app which contains the following symbols:

```
"ɛ" and "ɔ"
```

and would like them to display correctly in my app. I'm not sure if android supports these symbols and several search hasn't proved useful either.

If they are supported where can I find them or if you could help me with their respective codes.

The app is text-heavy and spans across several activities so I'm pretty sure using images is not the optimal solution here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you wanting to include them? In the XML? In resources? In code? Have you just tried using them directly?

Comment: Include a font file assets folder (if it is not included with the android platform.) You can find a starting tutorial [here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm)

Comment: have you tried to display them in the app ? `i'm not sure if android supports ...`, well that's easy to assert, isn't it?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using them under  `strings.xml` inside `res/values` directory

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, I've tried displaying them in the app in via the emulator and everything showed up as empty rectangles

Comment: that demonstrates that the font used in your emulator does not support those characters. Usually, most android devices use Roboto (see http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html). Displaying characters outside what is supported in the default font of the device requires an extra font, like @mek suggested.

Comment: @mek njzk2 I'm very new  to programming in general and am really not sure where to look for the kind of font that might contain these characters. Can you please give me some pointers about their names so I can try searching for them or maybe help me with some links? I would be extremely grateful in either case..

Comment: @user3237883 I think these characters are Latin letters. I am not sure if Android supports Latin out of box; so download a font from [here](https://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess)  and post your result. From the list **Alef Hebrew** supports Latin.

Answer (score 1):

"ɛ" => "\u025B"

"ɔ" => "\u0254"

More information:

[Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN E'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/025B/index.htm)

[Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN O'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0254/index.htm)

Comment: I had seen `\u0254` earlier but I tried it and got the empty rectangle all over. i saw that of `\u025B` at the same place but didn't bother to try. I've now tried both and I'm still seeing only the empty rectangles all over.I'm using them in the .xml as a string resource if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I look at quite a bit of language text from Cote d'Ivoire, which uses ɛ and ɔ extensively. They show up in most apps using standard Android fonts, but not their equivalent uppercase versions Ɛ (\u0190) and Ɔ (\u0186).
It is an open issue in the Android issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53217

Comment: I am honestly interested in the lower case but it doesn't work. Anytime I load the app in the Android emulator, it shows squared characters. I don't know if it's because I'm testing from an emulator or I will need to load it to my actual android device to get it ok.